# Issue with <table style="border-collapse:collapse"> Part of right border is cut off (screenshots attached)

Tags: html, css

I'm a new web developer (obviously). When I first noticed this issue, I thought it might be something quirky with the site I was working on. Since then I've worked on several other sites and noticed the same thing.

When I use the CSS property "border-collapse:collapse" to stylize HTML tables, sometimes the far-right border gets cut off when I load the page (both in FF and IE). Strangely enough, when I scroll up and down it occasionally fixes itself without reloading the page. It usually happens toward the bottom-right corner of the table, as the second screenshot indicates.

[screenshot1](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6271/tablebordercollapse1.jpg)

[screenshot2](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/1323/tablebordercollapse2.jpg)

Here's my HTML/CSS:

```
<table width="730" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ff9900;"></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ff9900;"></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ff9900;"></td>
  </tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```

What gives? Any ideas? Thanks for your time & effort!

Comment: Your images went away. You should probably use Stack Overflow's Imgur to host them, and insert them directly (which are easier together)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moz has problems with `border-collapse:collapse;` going back 10 years or so, it keeps getting fixed and then becoming buggy again (see bug track [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218956) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26614)).

Try adding a border to the table element like so:-

```
#your-table-name {border-collapse : collapse; border : 1px solid orange;}

#your-table-name td {border: 1px solid orange;}
```

*Please also note that this is a coding question and should really go to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Its also helpful to post the browser version you're using.*

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! You nailed it. I wasn't sure whether this question belonged here or on SO. Thanks for taking the time to answer nonetheless.